# Is there a common general setup for both Weil cohomologies and generalized cohomology theories?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

My question can be simply (and loosely) stated as follows:

> Is there a general (but not *too* general) construction that captures, as specializations, both Weil cohomologies in algebraic geometry and generalized cohomology theories in topology ?

(I must say I'm not an expert of any of the two!)

Comment: See perhaps this answer of Urs Schreiber: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6125/what-is-a-cohomology-theory-seriously/6154#6154

Comment: Also this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4214/equivalence-of-grothendieck-style-versus-cech-style-sheaf-cohomology/5815#5815

Comment: It seems I didn't notice that this question had already been asked. Thank you for the links to the answers and nLab.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the answer to the question as stated is no. However, Voevodsky's motivic homotopy theory does provide an adequate framework for both Weil cohomologies and generalized cohomology theories; there is a version of "Brown representability" theorem (representing object for a generalized cohomology theory) which is exploited in the applications to K-theory (Milnor conjecture and Bloch-Kato conjecture).