# Two definitions of Čech cohomology

Tags: cohomology, sheaf-theory

Hello,

I have found different definitions of Čech complex for sheaf $F$ od abelian groups on topological space $X$ with respect to the cover $\mathcal U$. One in Gelfand-Manin says to take product of $F(U_{i_0} \cap \ldots \cap U_{i_n})$ for all $n$-tuples of indices $(i_0, \ldots ,i_n)$, and one in Hartshorne says that one considers only stricly increasing indices $i_0 < \ldots < i_n$.

How can I see that cohomologies of these "two different" Čech complexes coincide?

Comment: In the Gelfand-Manin defintion it is assumed that a cochain $f_{i_0i_1\cdots i_n}$ is totally skewsymmetric (for the relevant definition of skewsymmetry) and there is a bijection between those and the cochains $f_{i_0i_1\cdots i_n}$ where the $i_j$ form a strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: These two chain complexes are different, so you can't show that they coincide: they don't. However, there is an inclusion of the second into the first. That inclusion induces a map at the level of cohomology, which turns out to be an isomorphism. Your question is then: why is it an isomorphism?

Comment: @Jose: If you assume total antisymmetry, then the two complexes are indeed isomoprhic. But there is another question to be asked: what about if you don't ask for antisymmetry? Then the first complex is bigger... but still has the same cohomology.

Comment: This is Proposition 2 in Section 20 in [Serre, Faisceaux algébriques cohérents], available here: http://www.mat.uniroma1.it/people/arbarello/FAC.pdf.

Comment: A key point is that the normalised and unnormalised chain complexes associated to any simplicial abelian group are homotopy equivalent.  This is explained in section 22 of May's "Simplicial objects in algebraic topology" (http://goo.gl/HhBlj) for example, and probably many other places.

Comment: This question was asked before http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10056/equivalence-of-ordered-and-unordered-cech-cohomology

Comment: @André: I stand corrected!  I had in fact not seen the unordered Čech complex before.